# Google cloud instance instantiation - Authorized GAE

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

My task is to create mysql insided google cloud sql. Following instructions I try to set an instance unluckily. The problem is a message

`"Authorized GAE applications must be in the same region as the database instance"`

at the time when I have checked both instance and application for that region setting and it is matching. I don't know what shall I put in the box `"authorized networks"`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC that means your IP address so you could (for example) connect to the SQL instance with command line tools. If you've already authorised your GAE app then that should allow it to connect to the SQL DB

Answer (score 1):

That message means you chose a region (EU for example) for your Cloud SQL that is different from the region of your App Engine application (US for example) where you created the Cloud SQL instance.

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appengine)

> **Note**: An App Engine application must be in the same region (either
>   European Union or United States) as a Google Cloud SQL instance to be
>   authorized to access that Google Cloud SQL instance.

As the GAE location can't be changed, you should change the region of the Cloud SQL instance, which also can't be changed. So you'd need to create a new instance in the exact region of your app.

The Authorized networks is exactly what Paul said. The IPs or subnetworks you want to whitelist to access your instance, only if you plan to access your instance with mysql client.